# In need for high variable capacitance

Tags: analog, filter, multiplexer, capacitance, variable

I am constructing a Chebishev or Butterworth audio filter (low and high pass), but I need to have all parameters highly adjustable - especially Fo and Q. For this purpose i would need to be able to adjust capacitance (and/or inductance in case I decide to go to the passive filter topology instead) very accurately and in very wide range - from 1nF to 10uF ultimately.
There are some IC variable capacitors with digital control (SPI/I2C) on the market, but the max capacitance offered is way too little. In order to solve this problem my first attempt was to use analog switches to connect /disconnect several capacitors in paralel in order to obtain the desired capacitance.
The capacitance (inductance) should be able to be controlled digitally, as the topologies require adjustment on all parts in order to obtain desired Fo /Q.
Low noise is of paramount importance.
My question: How would you address such a problem? Are there anywhere already available solutions for this? I was looking for an analog switch 16:1 or 32:1 which could be able to crosspoint-connect any of the inputs, but so far no any luck. All of them are connecting only one of all inputs to the output, or they are not bi-directional. Please help.

Comment: Have you considered going old school???  Relays are still very useful things.    Might point out, 1nF of capacitance is pretty darn small, and wire self-inductance may have an effect - a few centimeters of wire will have about 20nH of inductance.   Could cause you problems you don't anticipate

Comment: what are your filter specs? order? cutoff? gain? rejection? range? tolerance? ripple? group delay?

Comment: Have you considered switching with PIN diodes?

Comment: How would I address this problem? I'd probably go for a good ADC and some clever DSP or, as a second, more cumbersome and less flexible, option some switched capacitors filter.

Comment: For that sort of a change you're going to need multiple passive capacitors and switch between them with relays or transistors etc... It's going to end up being a somewhat discreet solution...

Comment: Reasons like this are why most processing nowadays is done digitally.

Comment: "DC to daylight" designs are very difficult. please tell us the frequency range this parametric filter needs to cover.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] and/or inductance *in case I decide to go to the passive filter* topology instead

> Low noise is of paramount importance

(emphasis mine) These parts tell me you are aiming for an active filter approach, in which case you'll only need opamps, resistors, and capacitors. Between these three components, by far the easiest to tune are the resistors. Whether you choose a switching array approach, or a potentiometer, or some exotic voltage controlled JFET, or telekinesis, it's up to you, but you should know that your beginning (emphasis mine):

> I am constructing a *Chebyshev or Butterworth* audio filter (low and high pass), but I need to have *all parameters highly adjustable* - especially Fo and Q

makes absolutely no sense. A Butterworth, or Chebyshev (or Pascal, Legendre, whatever other) filter implies fixed, well-known values for \$\omega_p\$ and \$Q\$, no matter the order. It's what makes a Bessel different than a Halpern, or any other. What you actually need is *an adjustable filter*, that's it.

However, you should know that using voltage controlled JFETs might sound like a good idea, but you also said that noise is "*paramount*", and while you will find low-noise JFETs on the market, it's a semiconductor and it comes with its own baggage. Plus, when you also consider that the specs for JFETs are all over the place... But then so would analog switches, they are also FETs under the hood, and they also come with their own problems. Relays, as proposed in the comments, might be the better approach, if you can tolerate audible noise, bouncing, and the few ms delay. While potentiometers require manual intervention, but if that suits you, then you'll have to consider the dirt and all the mechanical factors. In short, anything that is more than a resistor, will come with both conveniences, and inconveniences.

So, as with anything in the engineering world, it comes down to what are you willing to pay, and how much, for a certain goal.

If you need a *passive* filter, you may as well forget it, switching capacitors or inductors in order to have variable parameters is such a bad idea, I won't even make more comments about it. So that leaves you with variable inductors and capacitors. The latter can be those old variable plate capacitors: they are manual, but you *could* add micro-motors for adjustment... Or varicaps, but good luck with those. And the former could be tuned with a variable core, but that introduces nonlinearities on top of the same problems with the capacitors.

Comment: After some further research and reading probably I will stuck with a state variable filter. I will be filtering in the audio frequency range ( up to 20kHz), thus the big caps. This topology would require mainly resistors to be adjusted, and in order to be able to adress direct adjustment of Q without changing H or F (and vice versa) I plan to employ unbuffered DAC. This idea comes from an applicaton note tidu543 from TI site. Then incorporate a microcontroller to recalculate and set all resistor values upon the required Q/F/H. Should work in theory, but maybe any better ideas?

Comment: If you're going the digital way, then maybe it's better to use a dedicated DSP uC, where recalculating the coefficients "on the fly" should be much less of a hassle. Plus, those chips tend to have ADC/DAC builtin, plus dedicated hardware. I would say it's a much better choice than analogic -- in fact, by the tone of my answer you probably guessed that I would not recommend analogic for anything other than "fixed" designs.